# Whats is the usage of SHA1 fingerprint in google map api

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-api, cryptography, google-maps-android-api-2

What is the reason for add the SHA1 fingerprint in google api console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used  to uniquely identify your application. From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start):

> The Maps API key is based on a short form of your application's digital certificate, known as its SHA-1 fingerprint. The fingerprint is a unique text string generated from the commonly-used SHA-1 hashing algorithm. ***Because the fingerprint is itself unique, Google Maps uses it as a way to identify your application***.